# How to use better scroll the element when the parameter is a letter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my webApp project, I want to click a letter, and the relative content will be scrolled to display. 
Here is js code:

```
<script>
 import Bscroll from 'better-scroll'
 export default {
   name: 'CityList',
   props: {
     cities: Object,
     hotCities: Array,
     letter: String
   },
   watch: {
     letter () {
       if (this.letter) {
         const element = this.$refs[this.letter][0]
         this.scroll.scrollToElement(element)
       }
     }
   },
   mounted () {
     this.scroll = new Bscroll(this.$refs.wrapper)
   }
 }
</script>
```

I used vue 2.9.3 
But I got a error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "letter": "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
```

who can help me?

```
<div
  class="area"
  v-for="(item, key) of cities"
 :key="key"
>
  <div class="title border-topbottom">{{key}}</div>
  <div class="item-list">
    <div
      class="item border-bottom"
      v-for="innerItem of item"
      :key="innerItem.id"
    >
      {{innerItem.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I should add  :ref="key"

```
<div
  class="area"
  v-for="(item, key) of cities"
 :key="key"
 :ref="key"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a time when watch function run, `this.$refs[this.letter]` is not available yet. So you might want to check:

```
watch: {
  letter () {
    if (this.letter && this.$refs[this.letter]) {
      const element = this.$refs[this.letter][0]
      this.scroll.scrollToElement(element)
    }
  }
}
```

Your `cities` has different ref, you don't need to access [0] element

```
   watch: {
      letter () {
        if (this.letter && this.$refs[this.letter]) {
          const element = this.$refs[this.letter]
          this.scroll.scrollToElement(element)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have tested as you said, but it failed again

Comment: What's the error? Can you include template code of your Vue's component?